# Java Big Decimal Divide is not Accurate in Scientific Notation

Tags: java, bigdecimal

if we divide a BigDecimal number with scientific notation by another number, the result is not accurate:

```java
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("1.3E+4");
BigDecimal divide = bigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.TEN, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
System.out.println("The result is wrong: " + divide); //The result is wrong: 1E+3
```

#### Edit

I expected the `divide` value to be equal to `1300` but it's equal to `1000`.

---

If I use `bigDecimal.setScale(0).divide(...)` the problem will be solved but another problem will be raised:

```java
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("1.3E+4");
BigDecimal divide = bigDecimal.setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).divide(BigDecimal.TEN, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
System.out.println("The result is OK: " + divide); //The result is OK: 1300

BigDecimal bigDecimal2 = new BigDecimal("13.0");
BigDecimal correctResult = bigDecimal2.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
BigDecimal wrongResult = bigDecimal2.setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
System.out.println("Correct result: "+correctResult); //Correct result: 4.3
System.out.println("Wrong result: "+wrongResult); //Wrong result: 4
```

How I can do a reliable divide?

Comment: "The result is wrong: 1E+3" the result is not wrong, and not inaccurate.

Comment: Hi @federico-klez-culloca. I wanted the result to be equal to 1300.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail why the "wrong" output is wrong and what you expect it to be?